# Scrapy: ImportError: cannot import name Settings

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy import project, signals
from scrapy.crawler import Settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
import multiprocessing

class CrawlerWorker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, spider, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.result_queue = result_queue

        self.crawler = Crawler(Settings())
        if not hasattr(project, 'crawler'):
            self.crawler.install()
        self.crawler.configure()

        self.items = []
        self.spider = spider
        dispatcher.connect(self._item_passed, signals.item_passed)

    def _item_passed(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def run(self):
        self.crawler.crawl(self.spider)
        self.crawler.start()
        self.crawler.stop()
        self.result_queue.put(self.items)
```

I got an error while trying to use just CrawlerProcess(settings) from scrapy.conf.settings, it seems like there's a discrepancy between what the scrapy doc says here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

I am following an older scrapy version, I am trying to make it work with 0.16 of scrapy.

This is the error as soon as I run the python script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scraper import Scraper
  File "/home/me/spider/spider/scraper.py", line 6, in <module>
    from crawlerworker import CrawlerWorker
  File "/home/me/spider/spider/crawlerworker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import Settings
ImportError: cannot import name Settings
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the question please?

Comment: updated question with error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings
```